# suggestion to implement undersample and oversample

Tags: machine-learning, python, class-imbalance, smote

My dataset has the following class distribution

```
CLASS      FREQUENCY
2          22696
4          2541
1          2093
5          1298
3          1116
0          960
6          14
```

definitely I would want to generate a new sample, for that I will use [python imblearn](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/introduction.html) , I have three options:

1. oversample the minority classes
2. undersample the majority classes
3. choose a median class and apply both undersample the majority classes and oversamples the minority classes to equal the median class.

Later I will use the generated dataset to train three estimators RandomForest classifier, SVC and ensemble of both. I will choose the one with the best f-1 score. what would be the best option and which oversampling/undersampling algo should I use?

Answer (score 1):

In general, undersampling is not very useful because you are throwing any information about the features.

[SMOTE - Synthetic Minority Over-sampling Technique](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/references/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html) is useful for oversampling.

You might want to think about dropping Class #6. 14 is not a large enough sample for machine learning.

Comment: [But why is class imbalance an issue at all?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he)